# passing list between forms and adding at the end of it

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create a list `_Buffer` in Form2 with data from `Form3`, `Form4`, `Form5`, `Form6`, `Form7` and `Form8`. I made it work but only from 1 form if I try to add another elements from another list created in `Form4` for example while I already added from `Form3`... in `Form2` will show me only the elements from `Form4` without the elements from `Form3` I added previously. Here is how I do it:

Code for `Form2`:

```
ListArticle _Buffer = new ListArticle();
    public void SetData(ListArticle article)
    {
        _Buffer = article;

    }
```

Code for `Form3`:

```
public ListArticle _articles = new ListArticle();

    public ListArticle Articles
    {
        get
        {
            return _articles;
        }
        set
        {
            _articles = value;
        }
    }
foreach (Color color in dominantColours)
{
  MessageBox.Show(closestColor2(clist, color));
  tshirt_number++;
  _articles.Clothes.Add("T-shirt " + tshirt_number.ToString());
  _articles.Colors.Add(closestColor2(clist, color));
  Console.WriteLine("K: {0} (#{1:x2}{2:x2}{3:x2})", color, color.R, color.G, color.B);
  string hex = color.R.ToString("X2") + color.G.ToString("X2") + color.B.ToString("X2");
}
```

note: `closestColor2` returns a `string`;

and here is how I add them to the list in `Form2`:

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.Show();

Articles = _articles;
frm.SetData(Articles);
this.Hide();
```

`Form4` code is very similar to the code from Form3.. just another list.

Here is the `ListArticle` class:

```
public class ListArticle
    {
        public List<string> Clothes { get; private set; }
        public List<string> Colors { get; private set; }

        public ListArticle()
        {
            Clothes = new List<string>();
            Colors = new List<string>();
        }
    }
```

So basically I want to add elements I add in `Form4` at the end of the elements I add in `Form3`.

Comment: In `Form3, Form4, Form5...` you creating new instance of `Form2`? If so that is wrong. You need to have one Form2 instance and all other forms must access Form2s Article list.

Comment: @Reniuz I do something like this: `Form2 frm = new Form2(); frm.Show();`. How Do i make one `Form2` instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question you mention *"`Form4` code is very similar to the code from Form3"*.

Yet in `Form3` you make a new ListArticle: `public ListArticle _articles = new ListArticle();` If you do the same on `Form4` and the other forms than it is normal that your list is overwritten by each form. Every form creates its own new list.

I think what you want to do is create a public `Buffer` field on your main program `Program.cs` instead of on Form2. Like so:

```
static class Program
{
    public ListArticle Buffer = new ListArticle(); // Add this line

    static void Main()
    ....
}
```

This way you can access your Buffer from every Form with `Program.Buffer`.

And you can add new Articles to your buffer in each Form like this:

```
Program.Buffer.Clothes.Add(...)
Program.Buffer.Colors.Add(...)
```

Comment: Where do I declare something like that in my `Program.cs` ?

Comment: Why can't I use the list directly from `Program.cs` and have to make a separate variable `thisArticle;`?

Comment: @C.Cristi, you add the declaration of Buffer somewhere in between the curly brackets of static class Program { }, on the same level as static void Main().

Comment: Creating a 'thisArticle' variable is just one way to create a new article. The advantage is that you can set its properties from the entries in your form and otherwise manipulate it until it is ready to be added to your Buffer.

Comment: Can't I just go like `Program.Buffer.Clothes.Add("something")` and same with colors?

Comment: Tried it like this: `thisarticle.Clothes = "T-shirt " + tshirt_number.ToString();
                        thisarticle.Colors = closestColor2(clist, color);
                        Program.Buffer.Add(thisarticle);` but the thing is it gives me this error: **The property or indexer 'Article.Clothes' cannot be used in this context because the set accessor is inaccessible**

Comment: Yes, you can do that too. In that case, keep your `ListArticle` class. Don't replace it with the `Article` class I suggested. Create the `Buffer` in Program.cs instead of in Form2 like so: `public ListArticle Buffer = new ListArticle();` Than you can add Clothes and Colors with the code you suggested.

Comment: That's because the Clothes property has a private setter: `{ get; private set; }`. Replace it with `{ get; set; }`

Comment: Yep It finally works... update your answer with Program.cs and how you add them so people don't have to read all these comments.... I will pick your answer. **Great job! and thank you so much!**

Comment: One more thing.. I have a button in form1 if I press it, it shows me all the elements in the list and colors but when I click it and there is no element in the list it should show me something like "You have no articles" or something but it doesn't show me anything when I try to press it and I don't have articles inserted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132229/discussion-between-flip-and-c-cristi).

Comment: please see message

Answer (score 0):

With this line...

```
_Buffer = article;
```

... you are *replacing* your previous list with a new list. Obviosly, all entries in the previous list are lost in the process. You need to add the entries of the new list:

```
if (_Buffer == null) {
    _Buffer = new ListArticle();
}
_Buffer.Clothes.AddRange(article.Clothes);
_Buffer.Colors.AddRange(article.Colors);
```

Comment: It doesn't contain a definition for `GetEnumerator` and for method `Add` like this... I will post my `ListArticle` Class in the question. See the update!

Comment: @C.Cristi what doesn't work? There is a thousand ways how this could go wrong.

Comment: Also tried to add every string in particular like this: `public void SetData(ListArticle article)
        {
            if (_Buffer == null)
            {
                _Buffer = new ListArticle();
            }

            foreach(string item in article.Clothes)
            {
                _Buffer.Clothes.Add(item);
            }

            foreach(string item in article.Colors)
            {
                _Buffer.Colors.Add(item);
            }
        }`

Comment: I used debug and after I add the first items( t-shirt black) it's ok `_Buffer` gets the correct values but when I go to the `Form4` and I add (pants Black) and then back to `Form2` where `_Buffer` is, it's empty but can't figure out why and then it adds only (pants black) ofc.

Comment: @C.Cristi: It's difficult to say what's wrong without the full code, but one of the options is that you create `Form2` multiple times. That would throw away the combined list together with the form.